# Ansible: "this module requires key=value arguments" when key=value args supplied

Tags: ansible

I'm getting this error from Ansible 1.9.4:

```
TASK: [rabbitmq | add rabbitmq vhost] *****************************************
failed: [prod-sensu01] => (item={'name': u'/sensu'})
    => {"failed": true, "item": {"name": "/sensu"}}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments
(['name:', '/sensu', 'node:', 'rabbit',
  'tracing:', 'no', 'state:', 'present'])
```

But as you can see from the error message, the item is actually a key=value argument (hash).

Here are the variables:

```
# playbooks/roles/rabbitmq/vars/main.yml
# Set the rabbitmq vhost
rabbitmq_vhost_definitions:
  - name: "{{ sensu_server_rabbitmq_vhost }}"
```

And the role's task:

```
# playbooks/roles/rabbitmq/tasks/vhost.yml
- name: add rabbitmq vhost
  rabbitmq_vhost: >
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    node: "{{ item.node | default('rabbit') }}"
    tracing: "{{ item.tracing | default('no') }}"
    state: present
  with_items: rabbitmq_vhost_definitions
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key/value pairs of arguments for Ansible module passed as string should be separated by `=`, not by `:`. Correct task should look like this:

```
 # playbooks/roles/rabbitmq/tasks/vhost.yml
 - name: add rabbitmq vhost   
   rabbitmq_vhost: >
     name="{{ item.name }}"
     node="{{ item.node | default('rabbit') }}"
     tracing="{{ item.tracing | default('no') }}"
     state=present   
   with_items: rabbitmq_vhost_definitions
```

Why they're passed as string? Because you're using folded block scalar `>` after name of the module, in this line:

```
rabbitmq_vhost: >
```

You could also try to remove `>` scalar (and leave colons) if this module supports both ways of passing arguments.