# Ansible debug INI format

Tags: ansible

The task below

```yaml
  - debug: msg = "DB connection {{ dbConn }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "Hello world!"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I’m not familiar with mixing the YAML pattern with the INI pattern, but that’s what you’re doing with your debug task. Try rewriting the debug task with YAML syntax, e.g. remove the `=` and instead use a `:` after `msg` and correct with indented white space as necessary.

Comment: Also “Hello world!” is the default message the debug task will print if it can’t recognize one provided by the user.

Comment: I figured "Hello world" is the default message. It doesn't like a `:` after the `msg` (syntax error)

Comment: The syntax error sounds like an issue of whitespace, because it definitely works with a `:`. Put `msg: "DB connection {{ dbConn }}"` on its own line right after `- debug:` and indented 2 spaces over so it's parsed as a valid dictionary key-value property of the debug task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the value returned by a powershell script with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858441/how-to-read-the-value-returned-by-a-powershell-script-with-ansible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the white spaces around the equal sign "=". Space is used as a delimiter among more key=value arguments. See [Introduction to modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html#introduction-to-modules)

```yaml
    - debug: msg="DB connection {{ dbConn }}"
```

You'll be better off with [YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) format, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "DB connection {{ dbConn }}"
```

- See [Ansible: “this module requires key=value arguments” when key=value args supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883151/ansible-this-module-requires-key-value-arguments-when-key-value-args-supplied)
- [ansible-lint](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is your friend.